# Are stl algorithms classes with operator() or functions

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Recently I've taken C++ quiz and here is question from it:

*Select all concepts that are represented in STL by templated **classes***

1. Containers
2. Iterators
3. Functors
4. Algorithms
5. Exceptions

Obviously 1,2 and 3 are templated classes, but what about algorithms? I never thought about it, but algorithms can be templated functions, and also can be templated classes with operator().

Though, I think it does not matter and rather silly question, I'm interested in answer, because I only have number of my mistakes in quiz without knowing where I was right and where wrong.

tl;dr: **Are STL algorithms functions or classes with operator()?**

Thank you.

Comment: Functions. You can fire up the standard ([here's one draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)) and look at the declarations.

Comment: Just observe the form. Functions can be directly called. Classes has to be instantiated first.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath However, there could be global pre-defined instances of each class.

Comment: better term is "class templates", as in, templates used to build classes.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant With all the possible instantiations? I guess that would require infinite space. And a crystal ball.

Comment: @juanchopanza well, yes, you're right, in case of templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're function templates.

See [Algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)